# How to display selected month data from flutter dropdown selection using json

Tags: json, flutter

I have try to display Selected month data in dropdown selection in flutter , supposed I was select January then it display the January month record in json formate

```
String monthWiseGraph;
Future<String> getMonthlyGraphData() async {
String url = 'http://example.com/getAgentMonthGraph.php?month='+ monthWiseGraph ;
var response = await http.get(url);
return response.body;
}
Container(
        height: 130,
        width: 200,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 50),
        child: Card(
          // color: Colors.blueGrey,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 20, left: 20),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropdownButton(
                    hint: Text("Monthly",
                        style:
                            TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25)),
                    value: monthWiseGraph,
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    iconSize: 30,
                    elevation: 16,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    onChanged: (String monthNewValue) {
                      setState(
                        () {
                          monthWiseGraph = monthNewValue;
                          print(monthWiseGraph);
                          _showMonthlyAlert();
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    items: <String>[
                      'January',
                      'February',
                          .
                          .
                      'December'
                    ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(
                          value,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),                  
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

This is My January data

```
[
  {
      userId: "2",
      name: "Manish",
      total: "32"
     },
    {
       userId: "3",
      name: "Altaf",
      total: "31"
       }
  ]
```

This is My February data

```
[
  {
    userId: "4",
    name: "Prathamesh",
    total: "68"
  },
  {
   userId: "7",
   name: "Aniket",
   total: "62"
  },
  ]
```

[image: Here I display Data of selected month]

Above image I display the selected month data When I select january from dropdown then it display january data from json like manish and altaf and when I select february it dipslay Prathamesh and Aniket data below is this is normal graph
I am new to flutter

[image: this is normal graph]

[This is my drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIRT5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put "jsonDecode(response.body)" either in a variable or just change the "return" keyword. And then you can access the JSON api because "JsonDecode" will change the JSON data into a Flutter language. Make sure to "import" the file needed.

Comment: Sir, my url like http://example.com/getAgentMonthGraph.php?month=March (this is static url ) and this give me the response but I select month in dropdown ,

Comment: I guess the "url" is the problem because when I click the link, it give me "404 code"

Comment: updated url is http://us.rdigs.com/API/getAgentMonthGraph.php?month=March
please replace by February/April etc

Comment: Try change your "DropdownMenu" "onChange" value to () { setState() {getMonthlyGraphData}}

Comment: @ Aiman_Irfan sir, this is not working , My problem is when I select january it will dipslay janury data please check updated que in images and please check in code url 
'us.rdigs.com/API/getAgentMonthGraph.php?month='+monthWiseGraph;

Comment: So you want to display the data on the graph?

Comment: Yes,please check updated que this graph is normal graph but I want selected month graph

Comment: Use the data where you can plot the map. I don't know which packages you use for the graph but it involves a lot try and error. And try post the graph code too so others may help